# Formtastic and l18n: ' . ' (dot symbol) splits string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

In my Ruby on Rails application, I've created simple *pl.yml* file:

```
pl:
  contact_email: "My e-mail: mail@xxx.com"
  send_message: 'Wyślij wiadomość'
  formtastic:
    labels:
      contact:
        title: 'Tytuł wiadomości'
        content: 'Treść wiadomości'
```

In Active Admin page, I have a simple form and I've added a label tag with l18n:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Wiadomość" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :content
      f.label I18n.t 'contact_email'
    end
    f.actions 
  end
```

My problem is that the *contact_email* ('My e-mail: mail@xxx.com') is splitted by dot symbol ("."):

[image]

What should I use instead of ('.') in this string to keep this 'dot' in email address?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`= f.label :custom_email, label: I18n.t 'contact_email'`

First argument to label method is field name, that is automaticaly translated via I18n

Comment: Thanks for a help, but it doesn't work. I get following error:
`syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end f.label :custom_email, label: I18n.t 'contact_email' ^ `